# Missing DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Extensions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, openxml, openxml-sdk

I've installed OpenXML 2.5 package from NuGet but it's missing the OpenXML.Extensions reference.

Already tried to find searching google and nuget but without success.

Where can I get this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the official MS implementation of OpenXML 2.5, then you need to download it from the following link.  There is no official NuGet package for it currently.

[Official MS OpenXML 2.5 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425)

According to the following MSDN forum post, the OpenXML 2.5 package that is on NuGet is not official and may explain why you are missing some references.

[OpenXML 2.5 Nuget](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a2691940-a55b-4fd9-868d-37a1dcb472ae/open-xml-sdk-on-nuget?forum=oxmlsdk)

UPDATE:

Not sure if this is what you mean but OpenXML Document Save method has an overload to save to a stream.

```
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    var x = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Document();

    x.Save(memoryStream);
```

Comment: I've installed the OpenXML from Microsoft and still there's no reference to the Extension. I need this reference to save the document to a memory stream.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are in search of https://simpleooxml.codeplex.com/.  It is a library that has it's namespace set to `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Extensions`. As you mentioned, the ability to Save() a stream is indeed a part of the aforementioned library.

If this is not what you are looking for, could you please add some of your code so that I may analyze?

Hope this helps.